# Google Sheets SUBSTITUTE formula for creating an image path

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using the following ARRAYFORMULA to create an image path:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  if(row(A:A)=1,"@Icon",IF(
    B:B="",,SUBSTITUTE(
      "../../../../../../_Assets/Icons/"& LOWER(B:B&".png"), " ", "_")
    )
  )
)
```

#### What it does

Adding a path before the text and replaces all spaces with an underscore '_'. Here is an example:

| Name | @icon |
| --- | --- |
| A Tit(l)e | ../../../../../../_Assets/Icons/a_tit(l)e.png |
| Title - Subtitle | ../../../../../../_Assets/Icons/title _-_subtitle.png |
| Title text/string - Subtitle | ../../../../../../_Assets/Icons/title_text/string _-_subtitle.png |

#### What I want it to do

If possible, I would like to achieve the following:

1. Avoiding/removing characters in the list below like the forward slash `/` with an underscore `_` (see the last row in my example above)
2. It allready replaces all white spaces with an underscore `_` which is good. But when it sees a whitespace followed by a `-` and another whitespace it will output `_-_` but then I want only a `-`

So the current table above would output the following instead:

| Name | @icon |
| --- | --- |
| A Tit(l)e | ../../../../../../_Assets/Icons/a_tit(l)e.png |
| Title - Subtitle | ../../../../../../_Assets/Icons/title-subtitle.png |
| Title text/string - Subtitle | ../../../../../../_Assets/Icons/title_text_string-subtitle.png |

List of characters to be avoided/replaced with an underscore `_`:

```
# pound
% percent
& ampersand
{ left curly bracket
} right curly bracket
\ back slash
< left angle bracket
> right angle bracket
* asterisk
? question mark
/ forward slash
  blank spaces
$ dollar sign
! exclamation point
' single quotes
" double quotes
: colon
@ at sign
+ plus sign
` backtick
| pipe
= equal sign
```

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put list of avoided chars into column and use `REGEXREPLACE`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(A:A)=1,"@Icon",IF(A:A="",,"../../../../../../_Assets/Icons/"&LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A:A," - ","-"),TEXTJOIN("|\",0,D2:D23),"_")) & ".png")))
```

[image]

Comment: Great idea and solution! I got it working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do wonder however, if I have another Title like "Title & Co", I also want the ```&``` which outputs now three underscores to output only a ```-```. Is that something to add easely?

Comment: @Jonathan Then change regular expression for inner ```regexreplace``` from ```"-"``` to ```" - | & "```. i.e. ```...REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A:A," - | & ","-"),TEXTJOIN(...```. This will change ```Title & Co``` to ```title-co```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"@Icon", 
 IF(B2:B="",,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 "../../../../../../_Assets/Icons/"&LOWER(B2:B&".png"), " ", "_"), "_-_", "-", 1))})
```

Comment: Thnx for taking a look! However, not sure how this will solve the issues I've enlisted. User "basic" solved the question in the meantime.